# Creating custom searchbox for DataTables JQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

so as the title says I'm trying to create my own search box for the DataTables JQuery plugin as the default location isn't going to work for me and neither is there DOM configurations, reason being Im trying to get it inside a row of a table for display purposes.

I've got this html bit :

```
<th>Search by plan name and number :<br><input type="text" id="searchbox"></th>
```

and for the script that initializes DataTables I've got

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataTable = $('#table_id').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp>' //adjust the locations of defaults
    });

    // Custom search box
    $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
    dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
    }); 
});
</script>
```

and lastly in the CSS I added this bit, removing the default search box:

```
.dataTables_filter {
   display: none;
}
```

however whenever I type in my custom box nothing happens. Any suggestions or how-to's on editing this?

P.S: Im also trying to adjust the location of the page selector and "Showing # out of #" information bit, so if someone knows how to move those/recreate somewhere else (probably in the same manner as the search bar) then please feel free to share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit of code that fixes it! Turns out my original script was incorrect, this is how it should be:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dataTable = $('#table_id').DataTable( {
                "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom"lp>' //adjust the locations of defaults
            });

            // Custom search bar - **THIS IS WHAT CHANGED**
            $('#searchbox').keyup(function(){
                dataTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
            }) 
        });
</script>
```